# Problem with back annotated netlist signals naming for simulation purposes in Modelsim

Tags: simulation, system-verilog, modelsim, microsemi-fpga, systemverilog-assertions

Some of the labels used in **back-annotated netlist** descriptions generated by [Microchip (Microsemi) Libero](https://www.microsemi.com/product-directory/vectorblox-ai/5598-libero-soc) rely on forward slash naming conventions as shown below

```
...
top_entity\sec_tier/third_tier/signal_3
top_entity\sec_tier/third_tier/signal_4
...
```

I've been trying to display the signals into the [Siemens Modelsim](https://www.microsemi.com/product-directory/eda-partners/5158-mentor-graphics)'s wave viewer using the description shown below without any luck

```
add wave -group THIRD_TIER sim:/top_entity/\sec_tier/third_tier/*
```

The signals are added using a *.do macro

*Did I miss anything in the command to be able to see them?*

Comment: Look at how to escape Extended Identifiers in the Manual.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the main test bench is labeled as 'top_entity_tb', the following methodologies can be applied

## First method

Requires using the ModelSim GUI. Needs steps listed below

1. Go to top level testbench hierarchy (in the **Sim** tab)
2. Search for the instantiation of DUT. Using the description posted with the question, it should look like to something like this: top_entity_tb\top_entity
3. Right click on the entity of interest
4. Choose **Add Wave** in the options (Alternatively, Ctrl+W shortcut can be used)
5. The transcript window should then show something like this: `add wave -position insertpoint {sim:/top_entity_tb/top_entity/\sec_tier/third_tier/ /*}`. Notice that this command has multiple features (it uses curly brackets and it requires a space between the name of the group and the '/*' symbols)

## Second method

Add waveforms group directly into *.DO macro

Use expression shown below

```
add wave -group THIRD_TIER {sim:/top_entity_tb/top_entity/\sec_tier/third_tier /*}
```

Once again, the curly brackets and the space at the end **are required** in the command.

Note: Just found out that the '-position insertpoint' choice described in the previous method (GUI-based) is not needed.